# Unable to read html file outside src folder in java eclipse

Tags: java, html, file, eclipse-plugin

I am not able to read MyHtml.html file from MyFile.java which is located outside the source folder in java plugin project. Please find the project structure below.

- Project

  - src

    - MyFile.java
  - resources

    - MyFilesFolder

      - MyHtml.html
  - MyProduct.product
  - plugin.xml
  - build.properties
  - .classpath

I have tried InputStream, File, FileReader, FileLocator. But it says NullPointerException. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `Class.getResource(String)`

Comment: Show us source code and error messages/exception traces.

Comment: @Pavitra - I am still getting Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Are you using "/MyFilesFolder/MyHtml.html" as path to the resource?

Answer (score 0):

I will advice placing MyHtml.html on the same source folder for better accessibility.

Comment: I have moved the html file inside the source folder. But still I am not able to access it. Can you please help me in that ?

Answer (score 0):

try if this works but make sure u have the file on the same folder.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;



   Properties prop = new Properties();
                ClassLoader classLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
                File configFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("nameoffile.fileexetension").getFile());
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(configFile);
```